# Direct 2D gnuplot PNG animation?

Tags: animation, png, gnuplot

Can anyone please confirm that yes/no Gnuplot 4.5 (on CVS) can output 2D animated PNG files?  I have numerous datasets but one line that I'd like to show iteratively in 3 different places in my graph.  Can this be done *directly* from gnuplot or is this something that would need to be animated externally from multiple frames?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the demo scripts for the CVS version [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_cvs/). There is a [C2Gnuplot](http://c2gnuplot.tuxfamily.org/) for creating gnuplot animations (self-advertisement: it was developed by me).